# How to get Views field value in View twig template if the Views field is set to 'Exclude from display'?

Tags: views, 8

I have a Views fields twig template where I want to print the Views fields values manually.

For example, using: {{ fields.body.content }}

But this only works if the Views field is not excluded from the display.

Is there a way for me to print Views fields values if they are hidden (excluded from display)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall do it like this:

{{ row._entity.field_myfield.value }}

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I tried and got a WSOD error that logged "e Exception: Object of type Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList cannot be printed. in Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter() (line 465 of /PATH/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php)."

Comment: Try to kint fields, do you see the field you wanna render?

Comment: {{  kint(fields) }} does not output the variables for hidden Views fields.

Comment: Are you in the default view template ?

Comment: I'm using the fields template (views-view-fields--VIEW_NAME--page.html.twig

Comment: Ok, try to kint row

Comment: Thank you. Using kint(row) is was able to print to hidden fields llke: {{  row._entity.body.value }}